# Tkinter buttons don't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to code a packet sniffer using Python and scapy, and implementing a GUI using Tkinter. Everything seems to be working fine except for the "Quit" button. I'm using the code:

```
quitButton = Button(main_win,text="Quit", command=lambda:exitClick)
quitButton.pack(side="bottom")
```

The function exitClick() is defined as:

```
def exitClick(main_win):
    main_win.destroy()
    main_win.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

However, when I click on the Quit button, nothing happens. I don't have the button press animation, neither do I have the program closing. What do I have to change?

The abridged version of the code goes like:

```
import fcntl, easygui, logging
from Tkinter import *
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

inc_txt_str = ""
out_txt_str = ""

def exitClick(main_win):
    main_win.quit()
    sys.exit()

main_win = Tk()
main_win.withdraw()
frame_incoming = Frame(main_win)
t = Text(frame_incoming, width=45, bg="black", fg="white")
t.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side="left")
s = Scrollbar(frame_incoming)
s.pack(side="right", fill="y")
s.config(command=t.yview)
t.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)
frame_incoming.pack(side="left")

frame_outgoing = Frame(main_win)
t1 = Text(frame_outgoing, width=45, bg="white", fg="black")
t1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=YES)
s1 = Scrollbar(frame_outgoing)
s1.pack(side="right", fill="y")
s1.config(command=t1.yview)
t1.config(yscrollcommand=s1.set)
frame_outgoing.pack(side="left")

border_buttons = Frame(main_win)
border_buttons.pack(side="bottom")

quitButton = Button(main_win,text="Quit", command=lambda:exitClick(main_win))
quitButton.pack(side="bottom")

parseButton = Button(main_win, text='Parse IP')
parseButton.pack(side="bottom")



def eth_addr(a):
    b = "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (ord(a[0]), ord(a[1]), ord(a[2]), ord(a[3]), ord(a[4]), ord(a[5]))
    return b


class sniffPacket:

    def processIPFrame(self, pkt_type, ip_header, payload):
        fields = struct.unpack("!BBHHHBBHII", ip_header)
        dummy_hdrlen = fields[0] & 0xf
        iplen = fields[2]
        ip_src = payload[12:16]
        ip_dst = payload[16:20]
        ip_frame = payload[0:iplen]
        if pkt_type == socket.PACKET_OUTGOING:
            if self.outgoingIP is not None:
                self.outgoingIP(ip_src, ip_dst, ip_frame)
        else:
            if self.incomingIP is not None:
                self.incomingIP(ip_src, ip_dst, ip_frame)

    def __init__(self, interface_name, incomingIP, outgoingIP):

        self.interface_name = interface_name
        self.incomingIP = incomingIP
        self.outgoingIP = outgoingIP
        self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL))
        self.ins.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 2 ** 30)
        self.ins.bind((self.interface_name, ETH_P_ALL))
        pkt, sa_ll = self.ins.recvfrom(MTU)
        eth_header = struct.unpack("!6s6sH", pkt[0:14])
        dummy_eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth_header[2])
        ip_header = pkt[14:34]
        payload = pkt[14:]
        self.processIPFrame(sa_ll[2], ip_header, payload)

    def getPacket(self):
        pkt, sa_ll = self.ins.recvfrom(MTU)
        eth_header = struct.unpack("!6s6sH", pkt[0:14])
        dummy_eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth_header[2])
        ip_header = pkt[14:34]
        payload = pkt[14:]
        self.processIPFrame(sa_ll[2], ip_header, payload)
        main_win.after(500,getPacket())


    def all_interfaces():
        max_possible = 128
        bytes = max_possible * 32
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        names = array.array('B', '\0' * bytes)
        outbytes = struct.unpack('iL', fcntl.ioctl(
            s.fileno(),
            0x8912,  # SIOCGIFCONF
            struct.pack('iL', bytes, names.buffer_info()[0])))[0]
        namestr = names.tostring()
        lst = []
        for i in range(0, outbytes, 40):
            name = namestr[i:i + 16].split('\0', 1)[0]
            ip = namestr[i + 20:i + 24]
            lst.append((name, ip))
        return lst


    def format_ip(addr):
        return str(ord(addr[0])) + '.' + \
               str(ord(addr[1])) + '.' + \
               str(ord(addr[2])) + '.' + \
               str(ord(addr[3]))


    def get_ip_address(ifname):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
            s.fileno(),
            0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
            struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15]))[20:24])

def incoming_packet_callback(src, dst, frame_incoming):
    global inc_txt_str
    main_win.deiconify()
    inc_txt_str += "Incoming from "
    inc_txt_str += str(socket.inet_ntoa(src))
    inc_txt_str += "\n"
    t.insert(END, inc_txt_str)
    t.see(END)
    t.update_idletasks()

def outgoing_packet_callback(src, dst, frame_incoming):
    global out_txt_str
    main_win.deiconify()
    out_txt_str += "Outgoing to "
    out_txt_str += str(socket.inet_ntoa(dst))
    out_txt_str += "\n"
    t1.insert(END, out_txt_str)
    t1.see(END)
    t1.update_idletasks()

interface = "wlan0"
ip_s = sniffPacket(interface, incoming_packet_callback, outgoing_packet_callback)
#main_win.after(500,ip_s.getPacket)
main_win.mainloop()
```

I'm very new to Python and I believe I've made some major conceptual error which is causing this issue.

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: Linux
Running this on Ubuntu right now.
Also I'm very new to Python so my code is a mess. But if you're willing, I can show it to you if you can help me out.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've added the code example

Comment: I don't think you need all that code to reproduce this problem. This code is just riddled with errors that prevent the program from running, much less display a window. Please remove all the code unrelated to the problem in your question if you want people to  help.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I put in code which retained the functionality of the packet sniffer as well as drew a basic GUI.
Other than the first bit, all of it deals with sniffing the packets (after creating the parseButton). Which parts would you recommend me to remove?
I forgot to mention I joined StackOverflow just to ask this question which I've been stuck on for a few days. So I'm new here too. It seems like I was able to get the buttons working (they weren't working because of the main() function). Now I need to get the code running in the mainloop(), which it isn't.

Comment: "which parts would you recommend me to remove": Read and follow the instructions I linked to earlier. In short, remove as much as possible while still being able to demonstrate the problem. The "m" in "mcve" stands for "minimal".

Answer (score 1):

You use the lambda to be able to pass the `main_win` variable to your function, but then you only reference the function instead of letting the lambda actually call it.
Use:

```
Button(..., command=lambda: exitClick(main_win))
```

Comment: I just tried this. Didn't work. I think the issue is with the button not being clickable in the first place.
Normally, when you mouse-over a Tkinter button, it gets a little depressed. This is not happening in my program. I can't mouse-over or click it either.

Comment: Alright, from your question that didn't really become clear to me, because the way you used the lambda would indeed result in nothing happening when you click the button. Then you'll have to post an example code that demonstrates the problem, because from the code you posted there's nothing that would cause that behavior. Please read the link Bryan Oakley posted on how to make a proper example.

Comment: So I've reduced the extra code which had nothing to do with the issue, and brought it down to this.
Hope this is a better example.